# Assign output of dynamic SQL to a variable (without stored proc)

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I have the code below, where I want to get the id of a row via dynamic SQL.

Please note that variables `@posselect` and `@catselect` are filled, but I left that out for overview.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)
declare @posselect nvarchar(50)
declare @catselect nvarchar(100)

declare @bannerid int

SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 @id = id FROM banners
            WHERE publishdate < GETDATE() 
            AND depublishdate > GETDATE()' + @posselect + @catselect + 
           'ORDER BY [views] ASC'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @bannerid = @id output  'on this line I get the error

print '@bannerid:'+STR(@bannerid)
```

I get the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

Comment: Having difficulties posting code, dont know the tag usage. Replaced @ with [at]

Fixed it like this:
    declare [at]ParmDefinition nvarchar(250)
    set [at]ParmDefinition = '[at]bannerid int out'
    set [at]SQL='SELECT TOP 1 [at]bannerid=id FROM banners
    WHERE publishdate<GETDATE() AND depublishdate>GETDATE()' + [at]posselect + [at]catselect + '
    ORDER BY [views] ASC'
    EXEC sp_executesql [at]SQL,[at]ParmDefinition,[at]bannerid out

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't show that you are setting your @id field

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)
declare @posselect nvarchar(50)
declare @catselect nvarchar(100)

declare @id int
declare @bannerid int

set @SQL='SELECT TOP 1 @id=id FROM banners
WHERE publishdate<GETDATE() AND depublishdate>GETDATE()' + @posselect + @catselect + '
ORDER BY [views] asc'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,@bannerid=@id output  'on this line I get the error

print '@bannerid:'+STR(@bannerid)
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something but I don't see where you are declaring `@id` (as the error message suggests).

Try changing it to this:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(1000) declare @posselect nvarchar(50) declare @catselect nvarchar(100)

declare @bannerid int
declare @id int

set @SQL='SELECT TOP 1 @id=id FROM banners WHERE publishdateGETDATE()' + @posselect + @catselect + ' ORDER BY [views] asc'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,@bannerid=@id output 'on this line I get the error

print '@bannerid:'+STR(@bannerid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(128) = N'@id int output';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @params, @id=@bannerid output
```

I believe that's the correct syntax.